# How to change the icon of a C# program without using an IDE?

Tags: c#, powershell, msbuild, icons, csc

I have a single C# file (`Source code.cs`) that I compile with a PowerShell file (`Compile.ps1`) using Microsoft's compiler:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -out:"Program.exe" -target:winexe "Source code.cs"
```

It creates the executable `Program.exe`.

How can I change its icon? The icon of the executable which appears in the taskbar when running the program. I have `Icon.ico` in the same folder.

I only found [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1060918/How-to-set-an-icon-for-finished-csharp-project-WIT) asking the same question with a solution that I didn't quite understood.

Note that I'm asking specifically how to do it without any IDE.

Comment: The answer is in the link you posted:
_You can create another <PropertyGroup> node in the .csproj file e.g.
`<PropertyGroup>
<applicationicon>myicon.ico</applicationicon>
</PropertyGroup>
`
The .ico file should be in the same folder as your .csproj, .cs etc files_

Comment: @Diado I did tried that. I created a project file `Settings.csproj` and tried adding it to the compilation at the end `... "Source code.cs" "Settings.csproj"` but it throws the error `CS0116`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while of trial and error I managed to get it working with the `Settings.csproj` file as:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Compile">
    <Csc OutputAssembly="Program.exe" Sources="Source code.cs" TargetType="WinExe" Win32Icon="Icon.ico"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I don't understand why trying to use [PropertyGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/propertygroup-element-msbuild) would get ignored but then I found I could use [Csc's parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/csc-task#parameters) instead.

It can then be compiled with `csc.exe`:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe "Settings.csproj"
```

Or `MSBuild.exe`:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "Settings.csproj"
```

Which is good in case I need to change other project properties but for now a more simple solution that I found from the console output of running the above is that I can simply use the [-win32icon compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/win32icon-compiler-option):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -out:"Program.exe" -target:winexe -win32icon:Icon.ico "Source code.cs"
```

Comment: Nice solution without having to use third party software as Resource Hacker. Just a side note... "Program.exe" and "Source code.cs" do not need to come in between quotation marks and the full netframework path is also not needed. What is important: The `exe`, `cs` and `ico` files must all reside in the same directory, not necessarily in drive c. In Visual Studio, go to Tools>ComandLine>DOS prompt. Once there, type: `csc -out:myfilename.exe -target:winexe -win32icon:myiconname.ico myVisualStudiofilename.cs`

Comment: @LuizVaughan Thanks. IIRC, I was compiling the file through Windows PowerShell with the compiler that comes with Windows to see what I could do without needing anything installed, such as Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can using "Resource Hacker". Resource Hacker is a resource editor for 32bit and 64bit Windows applications. It's both a resource compiler (for *.rc files), and a decompiler - enabling viewing and editing of resources in executables (*.exe; *.dll; *.scr; etc) and compiled resource libraries (*.res, *.mui). While Resource Hacker is primarily a GUI application, it also provides many options for compiling and decompiling resources from the command-line.

Comment: From what I understood that's an application that can change any executable's icon, is that correct? If so then it might be a solution but I'll wait first to see if there's a way to do it programmatically without an external tool.

Comment: It is true. This is a program to modify DLL and EXE

Comment: @user7393973 There is no way "without a tool". Either you get one, or your program one yourself. How do you want to modify a file without using a software ? That's not possible.
If you say "no IDE" you say "I want to use command line tools only". Right ?

Comment: @Holger I think I didn't made it clear enough that it created a little misunderstanding. What I was looking for wasn't how to change the icon after compiling the code into an executable program but how to change it before. Sorry for the confusion.